# How to draw a line outside of an axis in matplotlib (in figure coordinates)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib has a function that writes text in figure coordinates (.figtext())

Is there a way to do the same but for drawing lines?

In particular my goal is to draw lines to group some ticks on the y-axis together.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.sin(x)*(1+x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y,label='a')

# new clear axis overlay with 0-1 limits
ax2 = plt.axes([0,0,1,1], facecolor=(1,1,1,0))

x,y = np.array([[0.05, 0.1, 0.9], [0.05, 0.5, 0.9]])
line = Line2D(x, y, lw=5., color='r', alpha=0.4)
ax2.add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But if you want to align with ticks, then why not use plot coordinates?

Comment: That would be better, but I can't get it to draw outside of the axes.  I'd like to draw where the tick labels are. (outside of where the plot is)  (I tried what would be basically `ax.add_line(line)` in your above example, but with coordinates that are roughly where the ticks are...)

Comment: @Max In that case, just set `line.set_clip_on(False)`.  Would you like another answer demonstrating this?

Comment: Thanks. set_clip_on(False) is a great tip.  I solved my problem by computing the line locations in figure coordinates, but now I know for the future.  No need to write another answer -- thanks again.

Comment: Instead of doing `ax2.add_line(line)` you can do `fig.add_artist(line)` so you can work on the whole figure instead of just one subplot