# How to add hierarchical axis across subplots in order to label groups?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having a set of different times series which can be grouped. E.g. the plot below shows series A, B, C and D. However, A and B are in group G1 and C and D are in group G2.

I would like to reflect that in the plot by adding another axis on the left which goes across groups of turbines and label thes axis accordingly.

I've tried a few thing so far but apparently that one's not so easy.

Does some body know how I can do that?

PS: Since I am using panda's `plot(subplots=True)` on a data frame which has already columns

```
      |  G1   |  G2  |
      |-------|------|
index | A  B  | C  D |
------|-------|------|
```

it might be that pandas can do that already for me. That's why I am using the *[pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)* tag.

[image]

Comment: What if you just add two a title; first above the A plot and second above the C plot? See [this page](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) for how to do that.

Comment: @Hami Hmmm, that would be another way to visualize the groups (besides color of course). I might try that yet it would be nice to know how I can solve such an example as shown above because that would also allow me to e.g. visualize a hierarchical clustering as well.

Comment: I see your point. Check out my answer for a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add group labels for bar charts in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create additional axes in the plot, which span each two plots but only have a left y-axis, no ticks and other decorations. Only a ylabel is set. This will make the whole thing look well aligned.

[image]

The good thing is that you can work with your existing pandas plot. The drawback is that is more than 15 lines of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(26,4), columns=list("ABCD"))
axes = df.plot(subplots=True)
fig = axes[0].figure


gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4,2)
gs.update(left=0.1, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=.2)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_subplotspec(gs[i,1])

aux1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2,0])
aux2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:,0])

aux1.set_ylabel("G1")
aux2.set_ylabel("G2")

for ax in [aux1, aux2]:
    ax.tick_params(size=0)
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_facecolor("none")
    for pos in ["right", "top", "bottom"]:
        ax.spines[pos].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_linewidth(3)
    ax.spines["left"].set_color("crimson")


plt.show()
```

Comment: I was hoping for an easier solution than this but apparently it's not something that `matplotlib` can do out of the box. :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I came up with. Since you did not provide your code, I did it without pandas, because I am not proficient with it.

You basically plot as one would and then create another axis around all your previous ones, remove its axis with `ax5.axis('off')` and plot the 2 lines and text on it.

```
from matplotlib import lines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
y3 = np.tan(x)
y4 = np.cos(x)/(x+1)


fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
ax1 = plt.subplot(411)
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(412)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(413)
ax3.plot(x, y3)
ax4 = plt.subplot(414)
ax4.plot(x, y4)

# new axis around the others with 0-1 limits
ax5 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax5.axis('off')

line_x1, line_y1 = np.array([[0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.5]])
line1 = lines.Line2D(line_x1, line_y1, lw=2., color='k')
ax5.add_line(line1)

line_x2, line_y2 = np.array([[0.05, 0.05], [0.55, 0.9]])
line2 = lines.Line2D(line_x2, line_y2, lw=2., color='k')
ax5.add_line(line2)

ax5.text(0.0, 0.75, "G1")
ax5.text(0.0, 0.25, "G2")

plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image]

Inspired by [How to draw a line outside of an axis in matplotlib (in figure coordinates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5021663/633093)

Comment: Thanks. +1 for a practicable solution but I think ImportanceOfBeingErnest solution looks a bit more matplotlib-ish :)

Comment: Thanks for the +1 and no problem, I have to agree with you. My solution is hackish, we need clean code on SO! +1 to ImportanceOfBeingErnest.